# How to stop looping process "Send Classpath Notification" on STS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I Use STS 4.3.1 RELEASE in Window 10 Home.
When I use auto-complication in java or jsp file, it suddenly work slowly. ( My STS Min/Max memory 3000M)

In progress tab, "Send Classpath Notifications" process has stated and soon be increased a lot.
Then STS soon be conspicuously slow performance, and then has "no response" (with white state)

[image]

In fact, In 4.2 or lower than other version of STS, I didn't meet this issue.

Comment: I find that situations are occured when file is changed or overwirte. If it's a small fix, the progress is so simple, but if it's large and lots of fixes, the progress are looping and adding to end of memory.... Why...?

Comment: Might be related to [STS4 issue #218](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/218).

Comment: @howlger, Thank you for your kindness! I will try ti soon!

Comment: If an update to 4.3.2 doesn't help, please file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and provide as many details as possible. If you have a project that you can share that would help to reproduce the issue, that would be awesome, too.

Comment: Sharing this project is protected by our company.. so I will try soon same condition to roll up issue. Thank you for yout mention! @MartinLippert

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Send ClassPath Notification` can be reolved with any of the following modifications based on the problem.

Better approach is to try doing each step and check whether your issue is still persisting.

Fix:1

In most of the cases, quick restart of the STS or Eclipse will resolve the issue of continues `Send ClassPath Notification`

Fix:2

Updating the Version 4.2.2 to 4.2.1

Fix:3

Navigate to `Windows => Preferences => Language Servers -> Spring Language Servers` and try disabling them

Reference : https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/218

Comment: That works for me, in my case was disabling Java Source File, thanks (y).

Answer (score 1):

Closing the STS IDE Task from Task Manger in windows solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I have solverd after updating spring tool plugin.